# qmake auto-generated Makefile compiler set incorrectly

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, c++14, qmake

We are doing a `C++` project for our uni and its final phase is passing the whole thing into a graphical interface using `Qt`.

We use `Qt5.4` and `g++-5`. These values have been set in the `QtCreator` project configuration by selecting the appropriate compiler, `g++-5`, and also adding options in the `*.pro` file such as `-std=c++14` and so on.

Nevertheless we are being stumped by an important issue. No matter what we try, when running qmake so as to auto-generate the precompiled files, in any `Makefile` generated by it, the compiler is **ALWAYS** set to `g++` and not `g++-5`. We are at the moment obliged to after using `qmake` having to change by hand the compiler in the `Makefile` on our own, even though we have told it **EVERYWHERE** that we are using `g++-5` and not the normal `g++`.

We have tried solutions like in this question: [Using c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127217/how-can-i-use-c14-features-when-building-qmake-projects)

And also changing the compiler in the `mkspecs` of the `Qt SDK`.

Both have been to no avail and we still can't get the auto-generated `Makefile` to use `g++-5` unless we change it by hand.

Is this a `Qt` issue or are we doing a step incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried something similar to `export set CXX="g++-5"`?

Comment: in the console you mean? i have tried setting exactly that in the .pro file though and it didn't help

Comment: `qmake -o QMakefile "QMAKE_CXX=g++-5"` according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html

Comment: done that as well: [Screenshot of .pro](http://postimg.org/image/ezhqh36sf/)

Comment: AH! Sorry for all the bother hahaha
It is solved now, I had linked my g++ compiler to g++-5 when I installed it ages ago but had forgotten (both g++ and g++-5 work on my pc, but they are the same) so it wasn't being an error, just my pc configuration getting in the way, thanks for the help though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all the bother.

It is solved now, I had linked my `g++` compiler to `g++-5` when I installed it ages ago but had forgotten (both `g++` and `g++-5` work on my pc, but they are the same) so it wasn't being an error, just my pc configuration getting in the way, thanks for the help though.