# Unable to add below statements in code QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using chrono library for calculating elapsed time but I am getting below warning.

> warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

I am beginner in C++ and don't know how to add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `makefile`?

Comment: No...should we add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 line in our .cpp file

Comment: You should add this in your compilation command (`makefile`). How did you compile you program?

Comment: I am compiling by using below command:                                                  g++ chronoprog.cpp -lmpir -o chronoprog

Comment: g++ -std=c++14 chronoprog.cpp -lmpir -o chronoprog

Comment: Thanks you so much. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using a qmake project, it should be

```
CONFIG += c++14
```

in the project file as mention in an answer to this post: [How can I use C++14 features when building qmake projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127217/how-can-i-use-c14-features-when-building-qmake-projects)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the flags in your compiling command:

`g++ -std=c++14 chronoprog.cpp -lmpir -o chronoprog`